# Sum - Group By for all data

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

tbl_user

```
id     username
1      kanda01
2      kanda02
3      kanda03
4      kanda04
5      kanda05
```

tbl_post

```
user_id      post_id
1            1
3            2
1            3
1            4
2            5
1            6
```

I would like to make a single query to get data as below

```
user_id     num_post
1           4
2           1
3           1
4           0
5           0
```

but I'm stuck. Please help me!

Comment: I replaced those RDBMS tags to `sql` - So If you need your SQL query based on a specific one, just add its tag ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT
    u.id, COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_post
FROM tbl_user u
LEFT JOIN tbl_post p
    ON u.id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: I removed my earlier comment because I was wrong and @Felix is right.

Comment: Do you really need that `ISNULL` around `Count`

Comment: For users with no posts. So that instead of `NULL`, it shows 0.

Comment: In both MySQL 5.6 and PostgreSQL `count(exp)` which selects no rows will give a `0`, not `NULL`. So `ISNULL()` - `coalesce()` in PostgreSQL - would not be necessary.

Comment: You don't need `ISNULL()` - `COUNT(p.post_id)` returns `0` for missing joins. See [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/214db/31)

Comment: Apparently, `ISNULL` is also not needed for sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple

```
select user_id, count(*) as num_post from tbl_post group by user_id;
```

`Group by` will apply the metric (`count(*)`) to each group.

To get the counts for users 4 and 5, you can join the tables.

Comment: This answer will not have the zero counts!

Comment: True. Seems the other answer has it covered.